# What pairs well with fig wine?

Tags: wine, recommendations, pairing

I am going to make some homemade fig wine this year and would like to know what pairs well with **fig wine**.

Here is the recipe I am planning to use: [Fresh Fig Wine](http://winemaking.jackkeller.net/reques6.asp)

> The common fig (Ficus carica) is most often eaten as dried fruit and rarely used fresh. It's not very sweet, so a true fig wine requires a great deal of additional sugar for the fig juice to ferment to completion. This recipe makes one gallon and can be easily adjusted for another quantity. The special supplies for this recipe are readily available at stores that sell wine-making supplies. - [How to Make Fig Wine](http://www.ehow.com/how_5415520_make-fig-wine.html?ref=Track2&utm_source=IACB2B)

Comment: Probably should be more specific so as to focus the answers.  Cakes?  Cheeses or yogurts?  Mushrooms?  Are you looking for variety in the entrée or in the dessert?  Is the drink to be served in courses, or are you simply planning to have guests who will serve themselves come for visit?

Comment: Uh... figs? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the taste of fig wine, but I do love figs, both fresh and dried, so I'm thinking it's along the lines of fruit cake (not a fave), minus the rum or brandy, but with it's own alcoholic pleasure (very much a fave). Some suggestions:

**Charcuterie**: bacon, ham, sausage, terrines, galantines, ballotines, pâtés, confit

**Cheeses**: goat, blue, Gorgonzola, camembert, Stilton, brie, mascarpone

**Grilled**: veg (corn on the cob, tomatoes), chicken (spicy or citrus), fish (tuna, swordfish)

And, from my [New York Times Recipe Box](https://cooking.nytimes.com):

**Savories**: particularly those that are light and those with citrus or sharp flavors...
 - [Grapefruit with olive oil and sea salt](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1016403-grapefruit-with-olive-oil-and-sea-salt)
 - [Onion & feta pizza](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1014841-grilled-pizza-with-grilled-red-onions-and-feta)
 - [Vegetable galette](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1016759-summer-vegetable-galette)
 - [Mustard tarte](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1015578-gerards-mustard-tart)

**Sweets**: especially flourless cakes...
 - [Almond Cake with Cardamom and Pistachio](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1013089-almond-cake-with-cardamom-and-pistachio)
 - [Orange and Almond Cake](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/3251-claudia-rodens-orange-and-almond-cake)
 - [Hazelnut Citrus Torte](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1016218-hazelnut-citrus-torte)
 - [Chamomile and Almond Cake](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1856-chamomile-and-almond-cake)

Answer (score 1):

While this is just a theory (I'm ignorant to the taste of fig wine! :( - it would seem that any food that pairs well with figs would do the trick. Such as Goat Cheese or Prosciutto...

This article may be a good reference... Couldn't even read to the end because it was making me so hungry :)

[27 Delicious Ways To Eat Fresh Figs](https://www.buzzfeed.com/christinebyrne/delicious-fig-recipes-for-every-occasion?utm_term=.vqjZApBAM#.hnGK6wA63)